# Why does Python detect self-references in list and dicts when printing them, but not in classes

Tags: python, self-reference

This is a question about the design of the Python language and is motivated by curiosity.

Python is able to detect self-references in loops and dicts when printing them

```
l = [1,2,3,[98,99]]
l[3].append(l)
print(f"{l = }")
# l = [1, 2, 3, [98, 99, [...]]]

d = {1:None,2:None,3:None,4:{}}
d[4][98] = d
print(f"{d = }")
# d = {1: None, 2: None, 3: None, 4: {98: {...}}}
```

but doesn't do it when class-objects have self-references

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self,name,parent):
        self.children = []
        self.name,self.parent = name,parent
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.name}: p={self.parent},"+\
    f"{[c for c in self.children]}"

top = Node("apex",None)
top.children += [Node("alpha",top),Node("beta",top)]
print(top)
# RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the repr of an object
```

It's easy enough to detect, and below is a decorator to do it. I wondered if there was some theoretical reason why it wasn't done automatically.

```
# Comments on my code are welcome, I want to improve
""" foo is a class-decorator.
It takes the parameter, a function, and returns another function
that accepts a class as a parameter, the second function returns an
amended copy of the class that has a new __repr__() function """
def foo(default=lambda x:"<...>"):
    def bar(origcls):
        # Note that default is available within this inner-program.
        # Amend __repr__ so that it saves the id of the object
        # and behaves differently if it has been seen before.
        # Use the class-static variable _reprlist to record calls
        # and the default-program to calculate the return if this
        # object is being re-visited 
        try:
            origcls._reprlist
        except:
            origcls._reprlist = set()
        oldrepr = origcls.__repr__
        def __repr__(self):
            if id(self) in origcls._reprlist:
                return default(self)
            else:
                origcls._reprlist.add(id(self))
                answer = f"{oldrepr(self)}"
                origcls._reprlist.remove(id(self))
                return answer
        origcls.__repr__ = __repr__
        return origcls
    return bar

@foo(lambda x:f"<<{x.name}>>")
class Node():
    def __init__(self,name,parent):
        self.children = []
        self.name,self.parent = name,parent
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.name}: p={self.parent},"+\
    f"{[c for c in self.children]}"

top = Node("apex",None)
top.children += [Node("alpha",top),Node("beta",top)]
print(top)
# apex: p=None,[alpha: p=<<apex>>,[], beta: p=<<apex>>,[]]
```

Comment: What do you mean "why"? *You* wrote the implementation of `__repr__`, and nowhere do you account for reference cycles which will cause a recursion error... that's *why*.

Comment: A test is implemented in the (equivalent of) `__repr__` method of list and dict. If you implement one in your own `__repr__` it will work the same...

Comment: @SergeBallesta the odd thing is the OP seems to understand that is possible, even providing an implementation that does it.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear although I did say at the start of the question that it was a question about the design of the language, maybe I should have said the implementation of the language. I was asking why the people who wrote the Python interpreter/compiler chose to put a test for self-reference on two types of structure and not another. I wish I could have studied formal structures of languages when I was younger and wondered if there was some formal distinction between between sets,lists, and dicts at one level and classes at a higher level.